# Different location for H1B visa than DS160

Tags: applications, h1b-visas

While filling out DS160, I selected the location as India-Chennai and paid the visa fee. Now, I booked an appointment with Chennai consulate. I'm trying to change the availability to an immediate date. Can I reschedule the interview with some other location, say, Hyderabad or Kolkatta?

Do I need to fill the DS160 in again or change the location in DS160?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a new DS-160. You can take your existing barcode confirmation page to any US consulate or embassy, even if it is not the one you originally specified when you completed the application. The consular staff will be able to scan the barcode and find your application.